# How can I use the same passValue function twice in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, variables, input

I want to pass the value of a input field in two spots. But my code only will pass it once. Is there a way to rewrite this to have it show up again down the code?

```
//HTML:
<input type="text" name="amount" onchange="passValue(this, 'preview_amount')"/>

//Outputs first value
<span id="preview_amount"></span>

//Outputs Nothing
<span id="preview_amount"></span>

//Javascript:
function passValue(e, target){
    document.getElementById(target).innerHTML = e.value;
}
```

Comment: what you twice? just call it again...
and that case it will always be called when the input field change

Comment: `id` should always be unique. Please keep that in mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your ids must be unique. Try this... It might work.

```
//HTML:
<input type="text" name="amount" onchange="passValue(this, 'preview_amount1', 'preview_amount2');"/>

//Outputs first value
<span id="preview_amount1"></span>

//Outputs Nothing
<span id="preview_amount2"></span>

//Javascript:
function passValue(e){
    for(var i = 1; i < arguments.length; ++i){
        if (document.getElementById(arguments[i]))
            document.getElementById(arguments[i]).innerHTML = e.value;
    }
}
```

With this you can pass any number of ids to `passValue` function without having to change it.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have duplicate element `id`'s within a DOM document. ids **MUST** be unique.

Using jquery, and unique IDs, your problem becomes simple:

```
<input ... onChange="passValue(this, '#preview_amount1, #preview_amount2');" />

<span id="preview_amount1"></span>
<span id="preview_amount2"></span>

function passValue(e, targets) {
   $(targets).innerHTML = e.value;
}
```

note the different IDs for the two spans, and how those IDs are passed withing the onChange handler.

Comment: Or you can set a class on the spans and send the classname to the function

Comment: that too. either way works. who knows what OP's plans are ultimately.

Answer (score 0):

Also try this one.

```
<input type="text" id="amount">
<div class="preview_amount"></div>
<div class="preview_amount"></div>
```

JQUERY

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type = "text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function() { 
      $('#id').keypress(function() { 
          $('.preview_amount').html($(this).val());
      });
   });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set class name for all the `spans` you want to update onchange and then set innerHTML according to this class so you won't have to pass different id's to the function.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LeZdY/)

```
<input type="text" name="amount" onchange="passValue(this.value)"/>
<span class="set_values_here" id="preview_amount_1"></span>
<span class="set_values_here" id="preview_amount_2"></span>

<script>
function passValue(new_value) {

    var els = document.getElementsByClassName("set_values_here");

    for(var i=0; i<els.length; i++)
    {
        document.getElementById(els[i].id).innerHTML = new_value;
    }
} 
</script>
```